# How do you properly build gpiod applications from Yocto?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to incorporate a CPLD programming utility on Github available at https://github.com/kontron/altera-stapl into my Yocto build but am getting undefined references to gpiod functions.  I have that it depends on libgpiod in my recipe.  Am I specifying the dependency correctly?

Here is my recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "CPLD STAPL Programming"

DESCRIPTION = "A userspace port of the Altera Jam STAPL Bytecode Player."
MAINTAINER = "Michael Walle <michael.walle@kontron.com>"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/kontron/altera-stapl"

LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=4641e94ec96f98fabc56ff9cc48be14b"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/kontron/altera-stapl.git"
SRCREV = "71540fb3dccf57ea0e43cef77d628244de402152"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "DCF8A052CD7908F484EAEE8A1924809056611E68EA28652E17C021BE836FAA6C"

DEPENDS = "libgpiod"

S="${WORKDIR}/git"

do_install () {
   install -d ${D}${bindir}
   install -m 0755 altera-stapl ${D}${bindir} 
}
```

These are the linker errors I am getting (there are a lot of them, not just this one, I can post the whole log if needed)

```
gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.2.0/ld: altera-gpio.c:(.text+0x3f4): undefined reference to `gpiod_line_request_output'
/home/gen-ccm-root/workdir/tools/poky/build-dev/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/altera-stapl/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.2.0/ld: altera-gpio.o: in function `close_jtag_hardware':
altera-gpio.c:(.text+0x4da): undefined reference to `gpiod_line_release'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:31: recipe for target 'altera-stapl' failed
```

What is the correct way to set the dependency?
Update: I am running Yocto Zeus on Ubuntu 18.04 (my GCC is 7.4.0).

Comment: what build mechanism is being used? autotools? cmake? meson? something else? it might alread be enough inheriting the respective class, so the proper cofniguration mechanisms trigger.

Comment: addendum: the correct way to set the dependency for yocto is  `DEPENDS`, which should be ok. its just that the package build also has to be aware of all the cross building pecularities.

Comment: I am using Yocto Zeus, I am not sure what it uses under the hood.  How can I find that out?

Comment: By looking at github.com/kontron/altera-stapl.git :) note: either your MAINTAINER is being wrong (e.g. you are not Michael Walle) or you should know, as you then work at Kontron. Read that as: the MAINTAINER field of the recipe refers to the maintainer of the recipe, not of the upstream source package.

Comment: The altera-stapl uses a good old Makefile.  I will fix the maintainer as well.

Comment: It is just a straight -lgpiod on the link line.

Comment: consider properly using pkg-config or whatever libgpiod provides, but as long as it works for you, have fun.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this issue was in the Makefile that was part of the GitHub project, and was actually fixed in a recent version.  In case anyone else ever wants to use this project, the final recipe is as follows (just update the SRCREV if newer versions are release):

```
SUMMARY = "CPLD STAPL Programming"

DESCRIPTION = "A userspace port of the Altera Jam STAPL Bytecode Player."
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/kontron/altera-stapl"

LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=4641e94ec96f98fabc56ff9cc48be14b"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/kontron/altera-stapl.git"
SRCREV = "852ff9d13cc06fef7d207abe12cc19ea5b67a16b"

DEPENDS = "libgpiod"

S="${WORKDIR}/git"

do_install () {
   install -d ${D}${bindir}
   install -m 0755 altera-stapl ${D}${bindir}
}
```