# Why doesn't Yocto generate the tarball when BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS is set?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I just added a new package to my Yocto build (this one: [How do you properly build gpiod applications from Yocto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741817/how-do-you-properly-build-gpiod-applications-from-yocto/59760428#59760428)), and it works fine as long as I am connected to the internet.  The problem is that I am now trying to make the tarball needed to support an offline build.

A little bit about the setup: I am running Yocto Zeus.  I work in a VM (Ubuntu 18.04) connected to the internet, but our build agents are not on the network, so we host a mirror.  I have this mirror mounted on /mnt/download-mirror.  I am trying to generate the tarball needed for the mirror on my VM.

This is the Yocto config that I am using:

```
BB_NO_NETWORK = "0"
INHERIT += "own-mirrors"
SOURCE_MIRROR_URL = "file:///mnt/download-mirror"
UNINATIVE_URL = "${SOURCE_MIRROR_URL}/uninative/2.7/"
BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = "1"
SSTATE_MIRRORS = "file://.* file:///mnt/sstate-mirror/PATH"
```

But when I run Bitbake (I using command `bitbake --runall fetch`) it completes, but I don't get a tarball for the new package I added.  I have looked for this tarball in the poky-downloads folder (the folder I would normally rsync to the mirror server), but it doesn't appear to be there.

Am I missing a configuration or something?  I have all the configurations noted in https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/How_do_I#Q:_How_do_I_create_my_own_source_download_mirror_.3f

EDIT - I also tried setting `DL_DIR ?= "/home/gen-ccm-root/Downloads"` in my conf file, but my command still said there was nothing to do, so I think the issue might be my bitbake command.  I have also tried `bitbake -c mi-dev --runall="fetch"` where mi-dev is my target (per 7.23.2 in https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#setting-up-effective-mirrors) to no avail.

Comment: Should they not be created be in the $DL_DIR, not in the $SOURCE_MIRROR_URL? Once they are created, you can move the to the SOURCE_MIRROR_URL>

Comment: @vermaete I agree, I am not seeing it in the poky-downloads folder.  I will update the question for clarity

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully someone can edit this and put in more information as to why, but I did manage to get it to generate a tarball.

1. Cleaned my VM which entailed deleting the sstate-cache and poky-downloads.
2. Modify the local.conf to have the following at the end (I think the DL_DIR is optional):

```
    BB_NO_NETWORK = "0"
    DL_DIR ="/home/gen-ccm-root/Downloads"
    BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = "1"
```

3. Run command: `source oe-init-build-env build-dev`
4. Run command: `bitbake mi-dev --runonly=fetch`
5. Mount the network share containing the download mirror.
6. Copy the files over: 
   `sudo rsync -av --ignore-existing --exclude=*.done --exclude=git2 --exclude=svn /home/gen-ccm-root/Downloads/ /mnt/download-mirror/`

I will update this as I learn more (I am still kind of a Yocto noob), but the issue appears to be related to a combination of Yocto not reparsing after changing the config, and the fact that the sstate-cache was still accessible and said everything was there.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a bit, with BB_NO_NETWORK it should not go out and fetch stuff from the internet.

If I understand it correctly you want a source mirror for some other build machines locally.

One way would be to share your DL_DIR of the one machine, which sees the internet.

Another way would be to use a source mirror for which you need the BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = "1" from above.

I use a web server to export my DL_DIR (which also contains the tarballs) and on the machines which should use it I use e.g. in local.conf or site.conf:

```
INHERIT += "own-mirrors"
SOURCE_MIRROR_URL = "http://mirror/source_mirror_zeus"
```

Just as a hint besides the sources you could also export SSTATE via SSTATE_MIRRORS, which will decrease build time a lot.

Comment: The `BB_NO_NETWORK` is set to 0, so it can get out to the internet.  I do have `SSTATE_MIRRORS` set when I am building normally (it is there in the question).  I suspect the sstate-cache was part of the reason I was always seeing "nothing to do" though.

Comment: Yes. Le's say you have everything pre built in SSTATE or SSTATE_MIRRORS, then DL_DIR will not be populated, since sources are not needed anymore.